# How to find the pixel width and height of device in Android, when not in Activity

Tags: java, android

I have just started to learn some Android development and need to find a way to get the pixel height and width from a class that isnt Activity. In my example this Class is called *BouncingBall*. I want to find out the screen size so I can change the speed of the balls to make it look like they are bouncing on the screen walls!

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WindowManager window = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
    Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
```

where you pass `context` from constructor.
or use `getApplicationContext()`:)

Comment: if you have a `Context` that'll do